# Getting an error while signin in flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

While doing signin with a wrong email or password i was expecting to get the snackbar i had entered but instead i am getting an error in my console.

error -

> Initial task failed for action
> RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - An internal
> error has occurred. [ INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS].

Authservice code -

```
  Future<UserCredential> signInUser(String email, String password) async {
    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    return userCredential;
  }
```

Login Code -

```
Future<void> signIn() async {
    try {
      if (emailController.text.trim().isEmpty) {
        return showWarningSnackBar(context, 'Empty Email');
      }
      if (passwordController.text.trim().isEmpty) {
        return showWarningSnackBar(context, 'Empty Password');
      }

      await AuthService().signInUser(
        emailController.text.trim(),
        passwordController.text.trim(),
      );
      if (!context.mounted) return;
      showSnackBar(context, 'Successfully logged in');
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        showErrorSnackBar(context, 'No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        showErrorSnackBar(context, 'Wrong password provided for that user.');
      } else if (e.code == 'INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS') {
        showErrorSnackBar(context, 'Login credentials are invalid.');
      } else if (e.code == 'invalid-email') {
        showErrorSnackBar(context, 'The email address is badly formatted.');
      }
    }
  }
```

I have not tried anything

Answer (score 6):

After facing a similar problem, I think this issue might because 'email enumeration protection' is enabled.

'Email enumeration is a type of brute-force attack in which a malicious actor attempts to guess or confirm users in a system by passing an email address to the API and checking the response.'

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection

The link details how to disable it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There might be many issues with showing that error.

1. Make sure that the password length must be six or more
2. Verify that your Firebase project's authentication settings are correctly configured.
3. Add `SHA1` and `SHA256` to your Firebase project
4. Confirm that your app is correctly configured to use your Firebase project. Check your `google-services.json` (for Android) or `GoogleService-Info.plist` (for iOS) configuration files and update them with the previous one.
5. Sometimes, network issues can cause authentication failures. Ensure that your device has a stable internet connection when signing in.

Comment: i added SHA1 and SHA256 keys to my firebase but still i am having the issue also i have a stable connection password is more than 6 digits and i am not on ios and i install firebase in my project using firebase cli

Comment: I'm also facing same error when trying to authenticate using wrong email. Although able to create new user from app. Added SHA1 SHA256 as well.

Comment: @SwapnilMusale Do let me know if you found in solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in Flutter Firebase Auth, and the 'email enumeration protection' policy I think is good for security purpose. So I check if the code contain "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS" as a workaround until this bug is fix.

```
e.code.contains('INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS')
```