# can't handle firebase Auth exceptions in flutter with firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, firebase-authentication

I am trying to handle exceptions that when a user tries to sign in with wrong password, wrong password will be printed to console, and when a user tries to login with wrong email and password, no user found will be printed on the console.

But when I try to login with wrong password on the else condition is executing. and when with wrong email and password, then also the else condition is executing. (Note: I am using the latest version of flutter and sign in with email and password is also active on firebase).
here is the code:

```
signIn() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text.trim(),
        password: passwordController.text.trim(),
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print(e.message);
        print("user not found");
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print(e.message);
        print("user not found");
      } else {
        print(e.code);
        print("something went wrong");
      }
    }
  }
```

this is printed on console when I use wrong password:

```
E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(21406): Initial task failed for action                    RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS ] I/flutter (21406): INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS I/flutter (21406): something went wrong
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your code in the "wrong password" section, you printed "user not found", it should be:

```
else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print(e.message);
    print("wrong password");
}
```

Secondly, the issue is not about the error code as shown in your console it is about **RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)** maybe "email enumeration protection" is enabled, check https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection to understand it and how ypu can disable it.

For more details check the issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145195/getting-an-error-while-signin-in-flutter-firebase)